# Getting Portable Devices using java

Tags: java, applet, device, mobile-devices, drive-letter

I am trying to access some files in a device (having **"windows CE"** application in it) that appears as **portable device** in windows 7 using java applet....

My device path is like

```
 "Computer\Attari's Device\myfile.txt"
```

Now i am trying to access file from it using the same address but it gives path error or file not found.

Similarly i used

```
"\\.\Attari's Device\myfile.txt"
```

but it resulted in same error tell me how to access portable devices using java applet

When i navigate to connected device and right-click on file and see it's properties then it shows it's location as

```
Location:  Computer\Attari's Device
```

Also when i open this file it is automatically placed in **temp** files of my computer.
I am using Signed Applet as well so there is no issue of file access denied

I also used

```
File.listRoots()
```

but it also does not list attached portable devices
I have to write some file in portable device using java applet

Comment: When you navigate to the device and right click on the text file to bring up the properties, how is the path listed?  Copy/paste it as an edit to the question.

Comment: @AndrewThompson it shows "Location:  Computer\Attari's Device"
now when i use "run" interface to access that device using above path it says file not found :( same is problem with java code
see my edited question as well

Comment: No, wherever you are getting that information is not what I mean.  Do as I said, navigate to the file, right click (this is Windows, right?) bring up the properties **of the text file** and copy/paste the `Location:` field (it does not look selectable, but it is).

Comment: @AndrewThompson When i navigate to file in connected device in windows 7 and right-click on file and see it's properties then it shows it's location as
Location:  Computer\Attari's Device
Also When i paste this location in Explorer i navigates to file successfully..
But this doesn't work in Run command and in my java applet code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution to above problem using JMTP library on

```
http://code.google.com/p/jmtp/
```

Here is my code

```
    package jmtp;
```

```
import be.derycke.pieter.com.COMException;
import be.derycke.pieter.com.Guid;
import java.io.*;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import jmtp.PortableDevice;
import jmtp.*;

public class Jmtp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PortableDeviceManager manager = new PortableDeviceManager();
        PortableDevice device = manager.getDevices()[0];
        // Connect to my mp3-player
        device.open();

        System.out.println(device.getModel());

        System.out.println("---------------");

        // Iterate over deviceObjects
        for (PortableDeviceObject object : device.getRootObjects()) {
            // If the object is a storage object
            if (object instanceof PortableDeviceStorageObject) {
                PortableDeviceStorageObject storage = (PortableDeviceStorageObject) object;

                for (PortableDeviceObject o2 : storage.getChildObjects()) {
//                    
//                        BigInteger bigInteger1 = new BigInteger("123456789");
//                        File file = new File("c:/JavaAppletSigningGuide.pdf");
//                        try {
//                            storage.addAudioObject(file, "jj", "jj", bigInteger1);
//                        } catch (Exception e) {
//                            //System.out.println("Exception e = " + e);
//                        }
//                    

                    System.out.println(o2.getOriginalFileName());
                }
            }
        }

        manager.getDevices()[0].close();

    }
}
```

**Donot forget add jmtp.dll files (that comes up with jmtp download) as a native library for more info see my answer on**

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12798530/including-native-library-in-netbeans
```

Comment: Do you have any example of reading file? As it's returning file name only

Comment: @DineshPhalwadiya Un-Comment the commented section in my above and change it according to your requirement