# Read and write data on mobile device connected do PC

Tags: java, file, mobile

I am trying to create a jar client that read a .db file inside a android tablet connected to users PC. Nowadays, i have to move the file to a windows file system manually do the action and move the file back manually.

Tried to use jmtp but did not work.

My mission is to read the file, copy the file to other location on the device and  execute some actions.

How can i do this?

```
    PortableDeviceManager manager = new PortableDeviceManager();
    PortableDevice device = manager.getDevices()[0];
    // Connect to my mp3-player
    device.open();

    System.out.println(device.getModel());

    System.out.println("---------------");

    // Iterate over deviceObjects
    for (PortableDeviceObject object : device.getRootObjects()) {
        // If the object is a storage object
        if (object instanceof PortableDeviceStorageObject) {
            PortableDeviceStorageObject storage = (PortableDeviceStorageObject) object;

            for (PortableDeviceObject o2 : storage.getChildObjects()) {
                if(o2.getOriginalFileName().equals("copagazmobile")){

                    PortableDeviceFolderObject storage1 = (PortableDeviceFolderObject) o2;
                    for (PortableDeviceObject o3 : storage1.getChildObjects()) {
                        if(o3.getOriginalFileName().equals("backupdatabases")){
                            PortableDeviceFolderObject folder = (PortableDeviceFolderObject) o3;
                            System.out.println(o3);
                            System.out.println(folder);
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println(o2.getOriginalFileName());
                }
            }
        }
    }

    manager.getDevices()[0].close();
```

Comment: What exactly does "I tried to use jmtp but did not work" mean?

Comment: i read the storage.getChildObjects(), get the dir that i want, but what next?

Comment: So you copied some code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/23990070/214525 which didnt work immediately, so you post this question. Did you do any research?

Comment: Sure i did, but i dont know how to access the path i want, and than copy the file...

Answer (score 2):

Was necessary to use a lib different that i was using called jmtpe
Code that i used to read the file and send to host:

```
    PortableDeviceManager manager = new PortableDeviceManager();
    PortableDevice device = manager.getDevices()[0];

    device.open();

    System.out.println("Dispositivo: " + device.getModel());

    System.out.println("---------------");
    System.out.println("Recuperando arquivo do Tablet");

    // Iterate over deviceObjects
    for (PortableDeviceObject object : device.getRootObjects()) {
        // If the object is a storage object
        if (object instanceof PortableDeviceStorageObject) {
            PortableDeviceStorageObject storage = (PortableDeviceStorageObject) object;

            for (PortableDeviceObject o2 : storage.getChildObjects()) {
                if(o2.getOriginalFileName().equals("copagazmobile")){

                    PortableDeviceFolderObject storage1 = (PortableDeviceFolderObject) o2;
                    for (PortableDeviceObject o3 : storage1.getChildObjects()) {
                        if(o3.getOriginalFileName().equals("backupdatabases")){
                            PortableDeviceFolderObject storage2 = (PortableDeviceFolderObject) o3;

                            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_hhmm");
                            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                            calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 1900);
                            Date data = calendar.getTime();
                            String idFile = null;
                            String fileName = null;
                            for (PortableDeviceObject o4 : storage2.getChildObjects()) {
                                String dataArq = (o4.getOriginalFileName().substring(15, 28));

                                try {
                                    if(new Date(format.parse(dataArq).getTime()).after(data)){
                                        data = new Date(format.parse(dataArq).getTime());
                                        idFile = o4.getID();
                                        fileName = o4.getOriginalFileName();
                                    }
                                } catch (ParseException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                            PortableDeviceToHostImpl32 host =  new PortableDeviceToHostImpl32();
                            try {
                                File f = new File( "c://sqlite//db");
                                System.out.println("Limpando diretório de manipulação: " + f);
                                FileUtils.cleanDirectory(f); 
                                System.out.println("Copiando arquivo: " + fileName );
                                host.copyFromPortableDeviceToHost(idFile, "c:/sqlite/db", device);
                                f = new File( "c://sqlite//db//"+fileName);

                                File novoArquivo = new File( "c://sqlite//db//copagaz_mobile_desenv.db");

                                InputStream inStream = null;
                                OutputStream outStream = null;
                                inStream = new FileInputStream(f);
                                outStream = new FileOutputStream(novoArquivo);

                                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                                int length;
                                while ((length = inStream.read(buffer)) > 0){
                                    outStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
                                }
                                inStream.close();
                                outStream.close();
                                f.delete();


                            } catch (COMException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            System.out.println("Arquivo mais recente é de: " + data);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    manager.getDevices()[0].close();
```

and send file back:

```
    PortableDeviceManager manager = new PortableDeviceManager();
    PortableDevice device = manager.getDevices()[0];

    device.open();

    System.out.println("---------------");
    System.out.println("Enviando arquivo para o Tablet");

    // Iterate over deviceObjects
    for (PortableDeviceObject object : device.getRootObjects()) {
        // If the object is a storage object
        if (object instanceof PortableDeviceStorageObject) {
            PortableDeviceStorageObject storage = (PortableDeviceStorageObject) object;

            for (PortableDeviceObject o2 : storage.getChildObjects()) {
                if(o2.getOriginalFileName().equals("copagazmobile")){

                    PortableDeviceFolderObject storage1 = (PortableDeviceFolderObject) o2;
                    for (PortableDeviceObject o3 : storage1.getChildObjects()) {
                        if(o3.getOriginalFileName().equals("restore")){

                            PortableDeviceFolderObject host =  (PortableDeviceFolderObject) o3;
                            try {
                                File f = new File( "c://sqlite//db//copagaz_mobile_desenv.db");
                                System.out.println("Copiando arquivo .db para o Tablet");
                                host.addAudioObject(f, "0", "1", new BigInteger("12345"));
                                System.out.println("Arquivo copiado");

                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    manager.getDevices()[0].close();
```

Comment: Have you got AccessControll exception beacause i am getting this error?