# Accessing Android Phone Storage connected via USB from Java on Computer

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to pull files off my Android phone using a Java program running on my computer. The phone is connected to the computer via USB. When I see the phones files in file explorer, it gives me "This PC\Pixel\Internal shared storage" as the address. When I try to use that and the file class in Java, it doesn't let me pull the file off the phone. Any suggestions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12775528/getting-portable-devices-using-java